# Not allowed to load local resource in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use camera in ionic and it's clicking photo but not showing photo.

```
getCamera() {
    this.camera.getPicture().then((res)=>{
        this.imageURL = res;
        console.log(this.imageURL);
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
    })
}
```

console showing me

> Not allowed to load local resource
> I am trying to use imageURL in my collection component like

```
<img src={{imageURL}} alt="" height="200" width="200" />
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. check documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera

Answer (score 0):

`Try This`

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
                quality: 90,
                targetWidth: 350,
                targetHeight: 350,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
                correctOrientation: true,
                allowEdit: true
              };
              this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
                if (imageData) {
                  this.imageURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
                }
              }, (err) => {
              });
```